# C# Linq to SQL Query Not Returning results but generated SQL works fine?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am trying to run the below code with LINQ to SQL. I know the results return back zero. But when I run the correlating SELECT statement that LINQ generates in SQL Server Management Studio and substitute the parameters for the values it returns a result. Any ideas?

```
var qryRes = (from res in dbHistoryContext.tblResumes
             where res.updateddate >= dtDateFrom.Date && res.updateddate <= dtDateTo.Date
            select res);
```

It returns the SQL code:

```
SELECT [t0].[resumehistoryid], [t0].[resumeid], [t0].[monsterid], [t0].[resumetitle], [t0].[updateddate], [t0].[updatedstatus], [t0].[source], [t0].[lastmodified], [t0].[modifiedby], [t0].[datechanged], [t0].[monsterhistoryid], [t0].[changetype]
FROM [dbo].[tblResume] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[updateddate] >= @p0) AND ([t0].[updateddate] <= @p1)
```

where @p0 = '4/01/2015 12:00:00 AM'
and @p1 = '04/30/2015 12:00:00 AM'

But for some reason the returned SELECT statement works when directly copies and pasted and ran against the dbContexts database but the LINQ to SQL doesn't seem to return any results when I do:

```
var lst = qryRes.ToList();
```

the count is zero. Any ideas? I know my connection is good. I know the datacontext is pointing to the right database - looked several times and refreshed my dbml several times. It only seems to happen when trying to do the date between another date. Which I know can be tricky. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Remove the date condition and check if you are getting results.

Comment: Are we sure that its not that its because you need to go to `05/01/2015 12:00:00 AM`?  Note that the 30th is the start of the 30th, not inclusive of the 30th.

Comment: Run the SQL profiler and check that's the query which is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to have to go with it being an issue with the comparison with the dates.  Can you guarantee that the dtDateFrom.Date or dtDateTo.Date is in the same format as what's behind the res.updateddate?

Also, give the following a try:

```
var qryRes = dbHistoryContext.tblResumes.Where(res => res.updateddate >= dtDateFrom.Date && res.updateddate <= dtDateTo.Date).ToList();
```